# Push View Controller from Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My tab bar controller is not embedded in a navigation controller.

On index 1 (which is embedded in a navigation controller) I have an alert that should show a view controller inside index 2 (also embedded in its own navigation controller).

I would like to jump to the view controller which is inside index 2 (called subVC).  The following code does not work.  `navController` is coming up `nil`.

```
     let subVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.subscriptionVC) as! SubscriptionViewController
     self.selectedIndex = 2
     let navController = self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.navigationController
     navController?.pushViewController(subVC, animated: true)
```